# Why do PHP error messages contain a link to the name of the name of the function in their HTML representation?

Tags: php

Why do PHP error messages contain a link, such as this error:

`<b>Warning</b>:  preg_match_all() [<a href='function.preg-match-all'>function.preg-match-all</a>]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in <b>/home/www/test.php</b> on line <b>93</b><br />`

with this link?:

`[<a href='function.preg-match-all'>function.preg-match-all</a>]`

Is the assumption that PHP will be configured to put a `http://www.php.net/` in front of that URL?  Or that a person will have a copy of the PHP documentation on their web server and that by clicking on that link they will be able to access information about the function?

This is just something I've been curious about since it seems that unless the error occurred on php.net, such a link would be useless.

I know it's possible to set up custom error handlers, etc.  My question is: Why is this the default behavior of PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, this is actually a pretty good question. I've always wondered that myself too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed supposed to link to php.net, but most default configurations have it turned off. And you are supposed to redirect it to a local manual copy. (Mine has /phpmanual/, where the php-manual package would probably put it; and I believe the package manager would uncomment the option then.)

The option [`docref_root`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.docref-root) in `php.ini` can be used to set it.

Answer (score 10):

You are able to set [docref_root](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.docref-root) to prepend the URI. it is intended to be used with a local copy of the manual but can used with an external one.

To turn off html errors altogether, set [html_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors) to 0.

Comment: iirc, the default config has these links turned off and it's recommended they stay off for a public site.

Comment: According to the manual, the default for `html_errors` is "1" http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php and only affects the presence of the anchor tag, not error messages in general. A production site should have all error messages off, which makes the `html_errors` setting moot.